# Multiplying power formal series when reindexing is required?

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

Normally, when I multiply the two following series:

$$\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n$$

$$\sum_{n\ge0}b_nx^n$$

I have:

$$\sum_{n\ge0}(\sum_{i=0}^na_ib_{n-i})x^n$$

Which is nice and intuitive. However, what if the exponents of x, or the indices don't match up? For example, what if I wanted to multiply these two:

$$\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^{100n}$$

$$\sum_{n\ge0}b_nx^n$$

If I were to try to do this I'd reindex the second series to:

$$\sum_{\frac{n}{100}\ge0}b_nx^{100n}$$

But then the indices wouldn't line up. Am I missing something?

Comment: $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^{100n} = \sum_{n \geq 0} A_n x^n$ where $A_n = \begin{cases}a_{n/100} & 100 \mid n \\ 0 & 100 \nmid n\end{cases}$, i.e. $A_n = a_{n/100} \delta_{100 \mid n}$.

Comment: That's a great way to think about it, thanks! Wouldn't that make the usual formula for multiplying series a bit of a pain to work with, though?

Comment: Yes, it can be a pain. This sort of approach with indicator functions is most useful when you're trying to use something like Mobius inversion. For literally multiplying formal power series, it's most intuitive to throw out the general formula, remember what proved it in the first place, and just collect terms as in Donald's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can nicely see the similarities when adding an intermediate step.

- On the one hand we have
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\sum_{l=0}^\infty b_lx^l
  &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{\color{blue}{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}}a_kb_l\right)x^n
  =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{\color{blue}{k=0}}^{\color{blue}{n}} a_kb_{n-k} x^n\\
  \end{align*}
- On the other hand we have
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{100k}\sum_{l=0}^\infty b_lx^l
  &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{\color{blue}{{100k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}}a_kb_l\right)x^n
  =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{\color{blue}{k=0}}^{\color{blue}{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{100}\right\rfloor}}a_kb_{n-100k} x^n\\
  \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In the middle sums we have rearranged the terms according to increasing powers of $x^n$. Consequently the conditions are $k+l=n$ resp. $100k+l=n$ besides $k,l\geq 0$.
- In the right-hand sums we eliminate $l$ by substituting $l=n-k$ resp. $l=n-100k$. Consequently is the upper limit of the inner sum $n$ resp. $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{100}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: I didn't even notice this response. This explains it perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @EachOneChew: You're welcome! Good to see, the answer is useful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} a_n x^{100n} \right)  \left(\sum_{  m=1}^{\infty }b_m x^m\right) = \sum \sum a_n b_m x^{ \color{red}{100n+m}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So to collect "like" $x$ terms, we need to list solutions of $100n+m=N$ ... this will give
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{N=1}^{\infty}  \left(\sum_{m \mid m+100n=N} a_n b_m \right) x^{ \color{red}{N}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\left.\begin{array}{r}
\ds{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{\mu n}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{\nu n}} 
\end{array}\right\}
\implies
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}a_{j}\, x^{\mu j}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}b_{k}\,x^{\nu k}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}a_{j}\, b_{k}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\delta_{n,\mu j + \nu k}\,\,\,x^{n}}
\\[2mm] & \ds{=} &
\ds{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}a_{j}\,b_{k}\,
\delta_{n,\mu j + \nu k}}}x^{n}
\\[2mm] & \ds{=} &
\bbx{\ds{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}a_{j}
\,b_{\pars{n - \mu j}/\nu}\,\,\,
\bracks{{n - \mu j \over \nu} \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}}}}x^{n}} \\ &&
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}